# How to create GraphQL object with arguments?

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

Is it possible an object with arguments? In other words, can I create an object for running queries like this?

```
{
    artifact(group: "com.graphql-java", name: "graphql-java") {
        group
        name
        version
    }
}
```

If yes, how?

I couldn't find a method for creating arguments in [graphql.schema.GraphQLObjectType.newObject](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/schema/GraphQLInputObjectType.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`field()` on the `Builder`](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/schema/GraphQLInputObjectType.java#L87-L91) to add an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations) and define it in a very straightforward way:

```
@GraphQLName("Query")
class Query {

    @GraphQLField
    static List<Item> items(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
        // Fetch all
    }

    @GraphQLField
    static Item item(DataFetchingEnvironment environment, @GraphQLName("id") String id) {
        // Fetch using the "id" argument
    }
}
```